# No output from print function

Tags: python, output

I am trying to create a program where a letter (in order), a,e,o,s,t, or r, is input and another letter, r,t,s,o,e, or a, is output. For example, if I were to enter a, I would receive r. I am also trying to make this case sensitive, so that if I were to input A, I would get R.

```py
secret=input("Enter string with 1 character: ")
letter_map="aeostr"
cipher="rtsoea"
cnt=0


while cnt < 6:
    if secret == letter_map[cnt]:
        if str.islower(secret):
            print(cipher[cnt])
        else:
            upper_ver = str.upper(cipher[cnt])
            print(upper_ver)
    cnt += 1
```

When I try to execute this line of code with an uppercase A or other string within the letter map

```py
else:
     upper_ver = str.upper(cipher[cnt])
     print(upper_ver)
```

I receive a blank output. I originally tried it as

```py
else:
     print(str.upper(cipher[cnt]))
```

I am not sure where I went wrong, but I am coming up short.

Comment: Your condition `secret == letter_map[cnt]` will never match since `"A" != "a"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better version:

```py
secret=input("Enter string with 1 character: ")
letter_map="aeostr"
cipher="rtsoea"

for cnt in range(6):
    if secret == letter_map[cnt] or secret == letter_map[cnt].upper():
        if str.islower(secret):
            print(cipher[cnt])
        else:
            upper_ver = str.upper(cipher[cnt])
            print(upper_ver)
```

As Abdul Aziz pointed out, the issue is with the first `if`. `letter_map` only contains lowercase letters, and in Python, uppercase doesn't match lowecase; this can be a source of frustration to new Pythoners coming from languages where lowercase *does* match uppercase. I also changed the `while` loop as it makes a little better sense among intermediate Python programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `secret.lower() == letter_map[cnt]` in first if statement.

```
secret=input("Enter string with 1 character: ")
letter_map="aeostr"
cipher="rtsoea"
cnt=0

while cnt < 6:
    if secret.lower() == letter_map[cnt]:
        if str.islower(secret):
            print(cipher[cnt])
        else:
            upper_ver = str.upper(cipher[cnt])
            print(upper_ver)
    cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop at all (unless I'm misunderstanding the functionality). Surely it's just a matter of...

```
if secret := input("Enter string with 1 character: "):
    secret = secret[0] # ensure only one character
    letter_map = "aeostr"
    cipher = "rtsoea"

    if (i := letter_map.find(secret)) >= 0:
        print(cipher[i])
    elif (i := letter_map.upper().find(secret)) >= 0:
        print(cipher.upper()[i])
else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Or...

```
if secret := input("Enter string with 1 character: "):
    letter_map = "aeostr"
    letter_map += letter_map.upper()
    cipher = "rtsoea"
    cipher += cipher.upper()
    if (i := letter_map.find(secret[0])) >= 0:
        print(cipher[i])
else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: It's better to look for `secret.lower()` and check whether the `secret` is uppercase afterward instead of looking for `secret` twice in `letter_map` and `letter_map.upper()`.

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned he is a new programmer; as such, I expect he would not understand how your answer's `:=` works.

Comment: @UndoneStudios I would expect a new programmer to work with the latest version of Python. The assignment expression has been part of the language since October 2019

Comment: I was just doubting that they would understand the walrus operator. For a simple task we shouldn't oversimplify it that it takes a little more effort to understand it.